# Finding a file in various locations

Tags: file-lookup

I have a central BibTeX file that I have in my home folder. Sometimes, I use it as a git submodule in the subfolder `central-bibtex`. The relative location can vary a bit. Since I want my preamble to do the work for me, I need it to find it in a couple of possible locations. Those include:

- `../../central-bibtex/Central`
- `central-bibtex/Central`
- `../../zentrale_BibTeX/Central`

Once I have a better syntax for this, I would like to add even more:

- `../central-bibtex/Central`
- `../zentrale_BibTeX/Central`
- `../../../zentrale_BibTeX/Central`

So far, I have this, which seems to work:

```
\IfFileExists{../../central-bibtex/Central}
{\newcommand{\bibliographyfile}{../../central-bibtex/Central}}
{
    \IfFileExists{central-bibtex/Central}
    {\newcommand{\bibliographyfile}{central-bibtex/Central}}
    {\newcommand{\bibliographyfile}{../../zentrale_BibTeX/Central}}
}
```

Is there some easy way to do this? I am thinking in Python:

```
dirs = ['../../central-bibtex', 'central-bibtex', '../../zentrale_BibTeX']
for dir in dirs:
    if os.path.isfile(dir + '/Central'):
        bibliographyfile = dir + '/Central'
```

I have tried TikZ and `\foreach`, but `\bibliographyfile` is not set to anything with this:

```
\newcommand\bibliographyfile{None}

\foreach \path in {
    ../../central-bibtex/Central,
    central-bibtex/Central,
    ../../zentrale_BibTeX/Central,
    /home/mu/Dokumente/Studium/zentrale_BibTeX/Central.bib
}
{
    \AtEndDocument{\path}
    \IfFileExists{\path}
    {\renewcommand\bibliographyfile{\path}}
    {}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\forloop` from `forloop` package might help?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to maintain a symbolic link from `TEXMFHOME/bibtext/bib/Central.bib`?

Comment: @cfr: Other people will clone the git repository containing the main file and also clone the repository that contains the bibliography into a location related to the first. So that link would have to be set up for every other user.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `\foreach` loop variable does not surive the loop, you need to expand the value that you are trying to save.. Below I use an `\xdef` to do that:

[image]

### Notes:

- I removed the underscores from the paths as that may cause some problems, but there should be solutions on this site that should help.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\bibliographyfile{}

\foreach \FileNameWithPath in {
    ../central-bibtex/Central.bib,
    central-bibtex/Central.bib,
    ../../zentrale-BibTeX/Central.bib,
    /home/mu/Dokumente/Studium/zentrale-BibTeX/Central.bib
}{%
    %\AtEndDocument{\path}% <-- not sure what this was for
    \IfFileExists{\FileNameWithPath}{%
        %\xdef\bibliographyfile{\FileNameWithPath}%
        % Per egreg's suggestions, replaced the above with:
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\bibliographyfile\expandafter{\FileNameWithPath}
    }{}%
}

\begin{document}

Located file: \bibliographyfile

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be more conservative and say `\xp\gdef\xp\bibliographyfile\xp{\FileNameWithPath}` (where `\xp` stands for `\expandafter`). Special characters should now be safe.